# Multiple progress bar circles on single row

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I am using this example to create a circle progress bar:
https://codepen.io/shellbryson/pen/KzaKLe

However, I would like to have multiple elements together on a row. I have tried this for two elements by adding two separate divs and two separate css IDs (both with `display: inline-block;`).

This successfully creates two progress bars together, but the first stays at 0%. In this case, the first should go to 90% and the second to 95% (as defined with `var end` in the js).

[image]

```js
var wrapper = document.getElementById('progress1');
     var start = 0;
     var end = 90;
    
     var colours = {
       fill: '#' + wrapper.dataset.fillColour,
       track: '#' + wrapper.dataset.trackColour,
       text: '#' + wrapper.dataset.textColour,
       stroke: '#' + wrapper.dataset.strokeColour,
     }
    
     var radius = 100;
     var border = wrapper.dataset.trackWidth;
     var strokeSpacing = wrapper.dataset.strokeSpacing;
     var endAngle = Math.PI * 2;
     var formatText = d3.format('.0%');
     var boxSize = radius * 2;
     var count = end;
     var progress = start;
     var step = end < start ? -0.01 : 0.01;
    
     //Define the circle
     var circle = d3.arc()
       .startAngle(0)
       .innerRadius(radius)
       .outerRadius(radius - border);
    
     //setup SVG wrapper
     var svg = d3.select(wrapper)
       .append('svg')
       .attr('width', boxSize)
       .attr('height', boxSize);
    
     // ADD Group container
     var g = svg.append('g')
       .attr('transform', 'translate(' + boxSize / 2 + ',' + boxSize / 2 + ')');
    
     //Setup track
     var track = g.append('g').attr('class', 'radial-progress');
     track.append('path')
       .attr('class', 'radial-progress__background')
       .attr('fill', colours.track)
       .attr('stroke', colours.stroke)
       .attr('stroke-width', strokeSpacing + 'px')
       .attr('d', circle.endAngle(endAngle));
    
     //Add colour fill
     var value = track.append('path')
       .attr('class', 'radial-progress__value')
       .attr('fill', colours.fill)
       .attr('stroke', colours.stroke)
       .attr('stroke-width', strokeSpacing + 'px');
    
     //Add text value
     var numberText = track.append('text')
       .attr('class', 'radial-progress__text')
       .attr('fill', colours.text)
       .attr('font-size', '30px')
       .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
       .attr('dy', '.5rem');
    
     function update(progress) {
       //update position of endAngle
       value.attr('d', circle.endAngle(endAngle * progress));
       //update text value
       numberText.text(formatText(progress));
     } 
    
     (function iterate() {
       //call update to begin animation
       update(progress);
       if (count > 0) {
         //reduce count till it reaches 0
         count--;
         //increase progress
         progress += step;
         //Control the speed of the fill
         setTimeout(iterate, 10);
       }
     })();
    
    var wrapper = document.getElementById('progress2');
     var start = 0;
     var end = 95;
    
     var colours = {
       fill: '#' + wrapper.dataset.fillColour,
       track: '#' + wrapper.dataset.trackColour,
       text: '#' + wrapper.dataset.textColour,
       stroke: '#' + wrapper.dataset.strokeColour,
     }
    
     var radius = 100;
     var border = wrapper.dataset.trackWidth;
     var strokeSpacing = wrapper.dataset.strokeSpacing;
     var endAngle = Math.PI * 2;
     var formatText = d3.format('.0%');
     var boxSize = radius * 2;
     var count = end;
     var progress = start;
     var step = end < start ? -0.01 : 0.01;
    
     //Define the circle
     var circle = d3.arc()
       .startAngle(0)
       .innerRadius(radius)
       .outerRadius(radius - border);
    
     //setup SVG wrapper
     var svg = d3.select(wrapper)
       .append('svg')
       .attr('width', boxSize)
       .attr('height', boxSize);
    
     // ADD Group container
     var g = svg.append('g')
       .attr('transform', 'translate(' + boxSize / 2 + ',' + boxSize / 2 + ')');
    
     //Setup track
     var track = g.append('g').attr('class', 'radial-progress');
     track.append('path')
       .attr('class', 'radial-progress__background')
       .attr('fill', colours.track)
       .attr('stroke', colours.stroke)
       .attr('stroke-width', strokeSpacing + 'px')
       .attr('d', circle.endAngle(endAngle));
    
     //Add colour fill
     var value = track.append('path')
       .attr('class', 'radial-progress__value')
       .attr('fill', colours.fill)
       .attr('stroke', colours.stroke)
       .attr('stroke-width', strokeSpacing + 'px');
    
     //Add text value
     var numberText = track.append('text')
       .attr('class', 'radial-progress__text')
       .attr('fill', colours.text)
       .attr('font-size', '30px')
       .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
       .attr('dy', '.5rem');
    
     function update(progress) {
       //update position of endAngle
       value.attr('d', circle.endAngle(endAngle * progress));
       //update text value
       numberText.text(formatText(progress));
     } 
    
     (function iterate() {
       //call update to begin animation
       update(progress);
       if (count > 0) {
         //reduce count till it reaches 0
         count--;
         //increase progress
         progress += step;
         //Control the speed of the fill
         setTimeout(iterate, 10);
       }
     })();
```

```css
 #progress1 {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
 }

 #progress2 {
  display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
 }

 .radial-progress { 
   &__text {
     font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
     font-size: 2rem;
     font-weight: bold;
   }  
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<div id="progress1"
        data-track-width="15" 
        data-track-colour="555555" 
        data-fill-colour="228B22" 
        data-text-colour="383838" 
        data-stroke-colour="FFFFFF" 
        data-stroke-spacing="1"> 
    </div>
    
    <div id="progress2" 
     data-track-width="15" 
        data-track-colour="555555" 
        data-fill-colour="228B22" 
        data-text-colour="383838" 
        data-stroke-colour="FFFFFF" 
        data-stroke-spacing="1"> 
    </div>
```

I have tried re-naming variables in the js to be unique for each element (i.e. `wrapper1` and `wrapper2` or `end1` and `end2`), but I cannot seem to get the first element to pay attention to the 90% end setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why so much code duplication? You could simply generalize the JS into a function and then use it on any amount of progress circles, just add another data attribute for the progress, e.g `data-progress`:

```js
var renderProgress = function(el) {
  var start = 0;
  var end = el.dataset.progress;
  
  var colours = {
    fill: '#' + el.dataset.fillColour,
    track: '#' + el.dataset.trackColour,
    text: '#' + el.dataset.textColour,
    stroke: '#' + el.dataset.strokeColour,
  }
  
  var radius = 100;
  var border = el.dataset.trackWidth;
  var strokeSpacing = el.dataset.strokeSpacing;
  var endAngle = Math.PI * 2;
  var formatText = d3.format('.0%');
  var boxSize = radius * 2;
  var count = end;
  var progress = start;
  var step = end < start ? -0.01 : 0.01;
  
  //Define the circle
  var circle = d3.arc()
    .startAngle(0)
    .innerRadius(radius)
    .outerRadius(radius - border);
  
  //setup SVG wrapper
  var svg = d3.select(el)
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', boxSize)
    .attr('height', boxSize);
  
  // ADD Group container
  var g = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + boxSize / 2 + ',' + boxSize / 2 + ')');
  
  //Setup track
  var track = g.append('g').attr('class', 'radial-progress');
  track.append('path')
    .attr('class', 'radial-progress__background')
    .attr('fill', colours.track)
    .attr('stroke', colours.stroke)
    .attr('stroke-width', strokeSpacing + 'px')
    .attr('d', circle.endAngle(endAngle));
  
  //Add colour fill
  var value = track.append('path')
    .attr('class', 'radial-progress__value')
    .attr('fill', colours.fill)
    .attr('stroke', colours.stroke)
    .attr('stroke-width', strokeSpacing + 'px');
  
  //Add text value
  var numberText = track.append('text')
    .attr('class', 'radial-progress__text')
    .attr('fill', colours.text)
    .attr('font-size', '30px')
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .attr('dy', '.5rem');
  
  function update(progress) {
    //update position of endAngle
    value.attr('d', circle.endAngle(endAngle * progress));
    //update text value
    numberText.text(formatText(progress));
  };
  
  function iterate() {
    //call update to begin animation
    update(progress);
    
    if (count > 0) {
      //reduce count till it reaches 0
      count--;
      //increase progress
      progress += step;
      //Control the speed of the fill
      setTimeout(iterate, 10);
    }
  };
  
  iterate();
}

Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.progress')).forEach(el => {
  renderProgress(el);
});
```

```css
  .progress {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 20px;
  }

  .radial-progress { 
    &__text {
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 2rem;
      font-weight: bold;
    }  
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<div
  data-progress="90"
  data-track-width="15" 
  data-track-colour="555555" 
  data-fill-colour="228B22" 
  data-text-colour="383838" 
  data-stroke-colour="FFFFFF" 
  data-stroke-spacing="1"
  class="progress"> 
</div>

<div
  data-progress="95"
  data-track-width="15" 
  data-track-colour="555555" 
  data-fill-colour="228B22" 
  data-text-colour="383838" 
  data-stroke-colour="FFFFFF" 
  data-stroke-spacing="1"
  class="progress"> 
</div>
```

Comment: Quick follow-up: what is the best way to pass a variable to `data-progress=`? i.e. if I have a `var` defined in a `<script>` tag.

Comment: You could just add it as an argument to the `renderProgress()` function instead, e.g. `renderProgress(el, value) { ... }` and then instead of `var end = el.dataset.progress;` do `var end = value;`